# create xml document and add or just add if document exixts

Tags: java, xml, jdom, jdom-2

here is my code:

```
Element FICHADAS = new Element("FICHADAS");
Document doc = new Document(FICHADAS);
try{

    Element fichada = new Element("fichada");
    //Nº TERMINAL
    fichada.addContent(new Element("N_Terminal").setText(props.getProperty("N_TERMINAL")));
    //TARJETA
    fichada.addContent(new Element("Tarjeta").setText(codOperario));
    //FECHA
    Date fechaFormatoFecha = new Date( );
    fichada.addContent(new Element("Fecha").setText(formatoFecha.format(fechaFormatoFecha)));
    //HORA
    Date fechaFormatoHora = new Date( );
    fichada.addContent(new Element("Hora").setText(formatoHora.format(fechaFormatoHora)));
    //CAUSA
    fichada.addContent(new Element("Causa").setText("2"));
    doc.getRootElement().addContent(fichada);
    XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
    xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
    xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("fichadas.xml"));

} catch(IOException io){
}
```

I'm creating a new document each time that i execute the program and i only want to create it if isn't exists, if the document exists just add the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) of `Filewriter`

> Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name with a **boolean indicating whether or not to append the data written.**

Also **FIRST** you must check if file exists:

```
File fichadas=new File("fichadas.xml");
if (fichadas.exists()){
     // append
     xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("fichadas.xml", true));
} else {
     // create 
     xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("fichadas.xml"));
}
```

**UPDATE** to avoid the declaration, you must use `Format.setOmitDeclaration(boolean)`. So you must add a format to the `XMLOutputter`:

```
// declare XMLOutputter 
XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();

// declare Format
Format fmt = Format.getPrettyFormat();

// set omit declaration to true
fmt.setOmitDeclaration(true);

// assign Format to XMLOutputter 
xmlOutput.setFormat(fmt);
```

Comment: thanks, now is adding the content but every time that i execute it adds this line: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> and the root tag in this case FICHADAS

Comment: now showed me that error: Multiple markers at this line
 - File cannot be resolved to 
  a type

Comment: organize your imports or change `File` for `java.io.File`

Comment: imports problem solved, but i have the same line (<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>) in the xml every time that i executed the code

Comment: I found that JDOM has this public boolean getOmitDeclaration()

Returns whether the XML declaration will be omitted., how can i use it?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you want to do. Just given a pseudo code:

```
File f = new File("fichadas.xml");
if(f.exists()){
//open file and write in it
} 
else{
//create new file
}
```

Comment: try by giving a path like "D:\fichadas.xml". Just check whether it works or not.